# Put the cursor at the end of jeditable textbox

Tags: jquery, input, jeditable, onfocus

I am using jeditable plugin for inline editing. When I double click on the field to edit, the cursor stays ahead of the value. The value of the textbox is dynamically generated. I want something that when I click on New Folder, cursor should stay at the end of FOLDER. Here's my live [Website](http://debug.bugs3.com/khuube/index.html) , Where u can add a New Folder from the left sidebar and double click on generated New Folder.

I have tried few available solutions here on focus on input field, they work on a static textbox, but I couldn't make them work with this jeditable plugin. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here's the jsfiddle to work on this plugin. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8bitrebellion/fd6o6z33/1/)

Below is my code of generating the editable folder in a list.

```
    $('document').ready(function () {

            txt_box = "<li class='animated bounceInDown foldertobedeleted' data-toggle='context' data-target='#context-menu' ><a class='folderlink'><span style='background-color:" + favorite + "' class='foldercount'>0</span><span class='editable foldername'>New Folder</span></a></li>";
            $("#folderlist li:last").before(txt_box);


            $('.editable').editable(function (value, settings) {
                console.log(this);
                console.log(value);
                console.log(settings);
                return (value);
            }, {
                type: 'text',
                onblur: 'ignore',
                event: 'dblclick',
                tooltip: "Double Click to edit",
                style: 'display: inline; ',
                width: '125px',              
               });

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, couldn't find solution for [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin, but plugin [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html) satisfied my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a heck of a time getting a jQuery reference to the **jeditable `<textarea>`** . I looked through the docs and many SO posts.  Apparently the `<textarea>` plays hide & seek and is not in the HTML when disabled.  Finally figured out this way to get to it.

Given some div where **jeditable** has been applied:

```
editableTextDiv.editable(..);
```

1. Set a listener for when the `<textarea>` is added  into the **jeditable** container div
2. When you have the object with the `<textarea>` present, then set the cursor position

   ```
   editableTextDiv.bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){

       console.log('editableTextDiv textarea changed');

       let self = $(this);
       let selfHtml = self.html();

       let isAlreadyProcessed = (selfHtml.indexOf('autogrow') > 0);
       if (isAlreadyProcessed === true){

           // console.log('self.html(): ' + self.html());
           console.log('skipping known data for inputNote [DOMSubtreeModified]');
           return;
       }

       let divTextarea = self.find('textarea');
       let isTextareaReady = (divTextarea.length > 0);
       if (isTextareaReady === true){

           console.log('inputNote gets [DOMSubtreeModified]');
           console.log('self.html(): ' + self.html());

           divTextarea.prop('selectionStart', 5);
       }
   });
   ```

Big thanks to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39424751/2162226

.. for the solution on detecting change for tag contents