# jQuery Call a function when content of a div changes

Tags: jquery

I have a span:

```
<span class="basket_amount">65.70</span>
```

This span is updated via an external script. 
If the amount changes I want to trigger a javascript function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.basket_amount').on('change', function() {
        versandkosten();
    });  
});
```

Currently it does not work. But why?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Event : Detect changes to the html/text of a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Meanwhile deprecated!**
While this should still work, be aware that `DOMSubtreeModified` has been deprecated see also [Mozilla Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified). Thx to @LuisEduardox for pointing this out.

**The original post:**
If possible I would try to call the wished function from the other script. But if you really want to listen for changes on the element you can make use of `DOMSubtreeModified`. If you change the content via jQuery though it will call your function twice! Therefore use vanilla JavaScript for changing the content.

```
function versandkosten() {
    console.log('called versandkosten');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $basketAmount = $('.basket_amount');
  $basketAmount.bind("DOMSubtreeModified", versandkosten);

  // test changing the content of the element via JavaScript
  $basketAmount[0].innerHTML = 77;

  // changing it via jQuery would call it twice!
  // $basketAmount.html(77);
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9our3m8a/

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified has been deprecated [Mozilla Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified)

Comment: THX @LuisEduardox for pointing this out, I updated the answer.

Comment: deprecated but still can be used, eerh?

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer uses the `DOMSubtreeModified` event, which is now deprecated.

Here is an updated answer using its replacement, the `MutationObserver` object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(e) {versandkosten();});
observer.observe($('.basket_amount')[0], {characterData: true, childList: true});
});
```

Fiddle sample https://jsfiddle.net/9our3m8a/257/

See also https://javascript.info/mutation-observer

Answer (score 5):

Try this one

```
 $('.basket_amount').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
      versandkosten();
    });
```

Comment: The least thing they can do is explain about code also the code is copy of another answer.